# Convert binary number to double matrix with 4 digits in every row

Tags: matlab, matrix, binary

I'd like to get a `2x4` matrix from 8 digit binary number
First row should be the first four digits,
and second row should be the last four digits:

```
b1 = 00000001
```

should return

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You filled out a box which says "Ask a question". Questions are denoted by a question mark (?), which seems to be missing here. Please [edit] the question to contain an actual question. You might want to read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

if you have an 1-by-8 array of bits, and you want to have a 2-by-4, you need to [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
b1 = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1];
reshape(b1, [4, 2]).'
```

Resulting with

```
ans =
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1
```

---

The result of `dec2bin` is a char array, you can simply convert it to `double` by subtracting the ascii value of `'0'` (the *char* `'0'`):

```
>> p1 = 6;
>> b = dec2bin(p1, 8);  % b is a char array (string)
>> B = b-'0';  % B is a double (numberic) array
>> reshape(B,4,2).'
ans =
 0     0     0     0
 0     1     1     0
```

You can play with it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/lkp3wR).

```html
<script src="http://ideone.com/e.js/lkp3wR" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Comment: p=4 and ans=dec2bin(p,8) and now i want this answr in 2*4 matrix

Comment: if it is in array than surely this create but answer with this dec2bin format

Comment: @PratikAnanadpara (1) please edit your question. see the comments you got there. (2) I edited my answer.

Comment: this is right for only for four but we take>> reshape(dec2bin(6,8)-'0',2,4) than answer is  0     0     0     1
                         0     0     1     0 but i want this answer in 0 0 0 0 (1st raw)                       0 1 1 0(2nd raw)

Comment: reshape(dec2bin(4,8)-'0',2,4) is give answer only for four-eight-two but if we do reshape(dec2bin(6,8)-'0',2,4) than it not create as want

Comment: p1=4

p1 =

     4

>> dec2bin(p1,8)

ans =

00000100

>> b = p1;
B = b - '0' ;
iwant = reshape(B,2,4)
Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

Comment: @PratikAnanadpara you forgot `dec2bin`

Comment: if add dec2bin than still not work

Comment: That's a nice trick you did embedding a direct link to IDEone with JavaScript.  That is something I'm going to have to remember from now on. +1.